# random item display in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, random, console, display

I want to parse subtitles from srt files (which I already did by following this [Parse a SRT file with jQuery Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145762/parse-a-srt-file-with-jquery-javascript)). But now I do want to display just one subtitle at the time (only text), I have tried with:

```
    document.body.innerHTML += subtitles[cont].text;
    var randomItem = t[Math.floor(Math.random()*t.length)];
    document.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
```

but the problem with it is that I get only one letter at the time, good thing is it random but I do want the whole subtitle. 
If I console.log subtitles[cont].text I get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc8fh.png)

And I can see they are separated. But I can't understand how to get only one of the two.

Comment: What is the variable `t`?

Comment: subtitles[cont].text = t;

Comment: Please update entire code, Seems parameters are missing

Comment: And for info, String is also Array line structure, so u can get text by index. May be by mistake u working on text rather than the array.

Comment: The code is basically the same as the one in the link, the only thing that's changing are the subtitles and that (ending) part mentioned above

Comment: It's very confusing.  Please show more code.  If t is what you say it is then, line 2 is choosing a random letter out of the text in subtitles[cont].text.  But you are saying this is NOT what you want?  Are you sure you don't want to just index subtitles[] ?  Please show the line that sets the variable t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fix it?

```
document.body.innerHTML += subtitles[cont].text;
var randomItem = subtitles[Math.floor(Math.random()*subtitles.length)];
document.body.innerHTML = randomItem.text;
```